# Oracle TNS listener not starting on CentOS 7

Tags: oracle, centos, tnsnames

I have installed Oracle 11g Release 2 Express edition on CentOS 7 machine. The installation process is completed successfully saying below.

```
Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...Done
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance...Done
Installation completed successfully.
```

When I do tnsping to the service I am getting below error.

```
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = i2b2)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

I then tried to start the listener and it's failing with below error.

```
TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NL-00280: error creating log stream /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/log/listener.log
 NL-00278: cannot open log file
  SNL-00016: snlfohd: error opening file
   Linux Error: 13: Permission denied
```

I searched a lot on forums and tried the given solutions there but could not solve the issue. What can be the issue in this case ?

Any help is really appreciated.

Edit:

Here is my tnsnames.ora file.

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = i2b2)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

And listener.ora file.

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = i2b2)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Environmental variables:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
export ORACLE_HOME

ORACLE_SID=XE
export ORACLE_SID

export TNS_ADMIN=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`

JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_65
export JAVA_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/local/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export PATH
```

Comment: :do you have privileges on the log directory?,looking to the error message its saying you dont have necessary privileges

Comment: :Also share the listner.ora and tnsnames.ora file ,need to see how you  configure

Comment: Hi Gaurav, please let me know if you need other details like hosts file details.